# Returning a value in Java

Tags: java, methods, types, return, if-statement

How do I write a method which returns a primitive datatype value when inside the method it has an if statement which returns a different datatype depending on the result?

```
int minimum = 5;
int students = 4;
int studentGrades = 100;

public double getAverage(){
    if(students >= minimum){
        return studentGrades / students;
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(null, "Sorry, you don't have enough students.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really return two different primitive types from the same method. With reference types you could return `Object`, that that isn't a good idea anyway.

Your `return false` looks like an error condition, so you might think about throwing an exception here:

```
public double getAverage(){
    if(students >= minimum){
        return studentGrades / students;
    }
    else {
       throw new IllegalStateException("not enough students");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the example you've given, you should throw an exception - the state of the object isn't valid for the method call, basically. You might want to use `IllegalStateException` for this, or choose a different type of exception. (That exception extends `RuntimeException`, so it isn't a *checked* exception. That may or may not appropriate for your real use case.)

(As an aside, the division in your sample code won't do what you want either - you should cast one of the operands to `double` if you want it to execute floating point division instead of integer division.)

Comment: Sorry, but how do I do that? I'm still learning the language.

Comment: Which would be an InvalidStateException if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @enchance: Stack Overflow isn't really a great place to *learn* a language - it's a good place to ask specific questions when you're not sure on one particular aspect. I strongly suggest you get a good Java book and do most of your learning from that. The topic of exceptions is too large to really do justice to within an SO answer.

Comment: ok. I mean, I am. But now I know about exceptions and InvalidStateException so thanks. I can take it from here. Returning a-1 was on my mind, I just needed to know if there was a more structured way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

public Object getAverage()

but then you should check the return class

Answer (score 0):

You can as example return a composite object that contains the score and a flag for success.
Or in the above version you could return `Double.NaN` to indicate the failure. Or as others have suggested throw an Exception in case of failure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no Java expert but I think the good practice here is to throw an exception if you have less than the required amount of students. If you must return 2 completely different values I suggest you encapsulate them in a class of your own.

Answer (score 0):

A java method can have only one return type. So you should try some other approche in handling this situation. As others above have pointed out you could throw a exception. Or you could use a nullable data type, and return null when this special condition is true. But this is ugly and is not recommended.